# Android Stop Emulator from Command Line

Tags: android, android-emulator

This question is identical to [How to shut down Android emulator via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912403/how-to-shut-down-android-emulator-via-cmd).

However, after attempting the suggested solution from the first answer `adb emu kill` has not proven successful for me.

I am automating unit tests for an android application. My bash script runs on a headless machine. It creates an android device using `android create avd` and executes `emulator` with the `-no-window` attribute. It then compiles the test project, connects to the emulator using `adb`, installs the project and executes my tests. This all works fine.

Now I need to terminate the emulator process, and just like the referenced post, I am only able to do this using `kill -9`.

The Google tutorial [Managing AVDs from the Command Line](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html) only mentions how to stop emulators within a GUI environment.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 339, accepted):

May be `adb kill-server` helps for you?

or

`adb -s emulator-5544 emu kill`, where `emulator-5544` - emulator name.

For Linux users it will be

`adb devices | grep emulator | cut -f1 | while read line; do adb -s $line emu kill; done`

Comment: adb kill-server stops adb but does not stop the emulator process. And the emu kill statement always returns emulator not found

Comment: emulator not found? Never believe of that. if you start emulator - you have emulator. Didn't? Try to kil emulator of another port. Numbers of ports consists in link above.

Comment: Your comment on verifying the port I am using was correct. Can't believe I over read that part in the document you posted. Had been assuming that the argument for -s was the name of the emulator.

Comment: neither work on osx using latest available sdks at this date

Comment: `adb -s emulator-5554 emu kill` does shut down the emulator but the command does not terminate and blocks forever :/

Comment: to anyone who was confused by this, you can find the emulator name by using `adb devices`.

Comment: @funkybro my phone is currently running 6.0.1 and I can confirm that ADB still exists (I use my phone to test programs made by the android SDK and NDK almost daily).

Comment: on Windows 10, the "adb -s emulator-5554 emu kill" command blocks on the command line. (Same issue exists in both windows cmd line and gitbash shell)

Comment: Small typo:) where `emulator-5554` should be the case:)

Answer (score 79):

## FOR MAC:

1. Run:

```
ps -ax | grep emulator
```

which gives you a wide result. Something like:

```
 6617 ??         9:05.54 /Users/nav/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64 -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_One_API_29
 6619 ??         0:06.10 /Users/nav/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator64-crash-service -pipe com.google.AndroidEmulator.CrashService.6617 -ppid 6617 -data-dir /tmp/android-nav/
 6658 ??         0:07.93 /Users/nav/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/libexec/QtWebEngineProcess --type=renderer --disable-accelerated-video-decode --disable-gpu-memory-buffer-video-frames --disable-pepper-3d-image-chromium --enable-threaded-compositing --file-url-path-alias=/gen=/Users/nav/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/libexec/gen --enable-features=AllowContentInitiatedDataUrlNavigations --disable-features=MacV2Sandbox,MojoVideoCapture,SurfaceSynchronization,UseVideoCaptureApiForDevToolsSnapshots --disable-gpu-compositing --service-pipe-token=15570406721898250245 --lang=en-US --webengine-schemes=qrc:sLV --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --service-request-channel-token=15570406721898250245 --renderer-client-id=2
 6659 ??         0:01.11 /Users/nav/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/libexec/QtWebEngineProcess --type=renderer --disable-accelerated-video-decode --disable-gpu-memory-buffer-video-frames --disable-pepper-3d-image-chromium --enable-threaded-compositing --file-url-path-alias=/gen=/Users/nav/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/libexec/gen --enable-features=AllowContentInitiatedDataUrlNavigations --disable-features=MacV2Sandbox,MojoVideoCapture,SurfaceSynchronization,UseVideoCaptureApiForDevToolsSnapshots --disable-gpu-compositing --service-pipe-token=--lang=en-US --webengine-schemes=qrc:sLV --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --service-request-channel-token=  --renderer-client-id=3
10030 ttys000    0:00.00 grep emulator
```

2. The first (left) column is the process ID (PID) that you are looking for.
3. Find the PID in the first (top) row. In the above example, it's `6617`.
4. Kill that process:

```
kill PID
```

In my case, the command is:

```
kill 6617
```

5. Usually, killing the first process in enough to stop the emulator, but if that doesn't work, you can:

   5.1. try killing other processes as well.

   5.2 kill with `-9` (force kill):

```
kill -9 PID
```

Comment: Do not use -9 to kill the emulator. Normal `kill` suffices. `-9` crashes the process and skips all cleanup, which can lead to problems.

Comment: `Kill` alone didn't kill the process for me, `kill -9` did.

Comment: running the kill command didn't work for me, maybe I didn't find the good process to kill or maybe I missed to force (-9). Then I opened the macos activity monitor that list the processes and my emulator was at the top. I double click on it and force quit. That finally worked.

Answer (score 54):

To stop all running emulators we use this command:

```
adb devices | grep emulator | cut -f1 | while read line; do adb -s $line emu kill; done
```

Comment: then, make it a bash alias ;)

Answer (score 32):

if

```
 adb kill-server
```

doesn't work. Use :

```
 adb emu kill
```

this will kill all the emulators

If multiple emulators are present then use:

```
adb -s * emu kill
```

Answer (score 21):

Sometimes the command

```
adb -s emulator-5554 emu kill
```

did not work on my CI servers or desktops, for unknown reason. 
I think on Windows it's OK to kill the process of qemu, just like

```
Taskkill /IM qemu-system-x86_64.exe /F /T
```

Comment: This is what worked very well for me in Windows 11. You just need to specify that this command must be executed in an Administrator command prompt. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 15):

I can close it with:

```
adb shell reboot -p
```

Comment: What does the `-p` option do? Power off instead of just reboot? Are there docs that this is pulled from? Thanks!

Comment: I found out elsewhere that it just stands for "power". Strange syntax but it works well. It seems to be more graceful compared to `kill` and `emu kill`.

Answer (score 9):

The other answer didn't work for me (on Windows 7). But this worked:

```
telnet localhost 5554
kill
```

Comment: but before the Telnet feature needs to be activated through  Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off > Telnet Client

Comment: `kill` doesn't seem to be a command in emulators running Android 9, possibly earlier too

Answer (score 9):

Why not just do

```
adb reboot bootloader
```

Comment: this eventually worked for me, maybe after calling the other above commands

Comment: Really!
I thought we can not restart the android emulator through 'reboot' command
which version you are using?

Answer (score 9):

to get your devices name try to run this on Android Studio terminal

```
adb devices
```

after you get devices name, kill app with this comment

```
adb -s emulator-5554 emu kill
```

where

> emulator-5554

is your device name

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to have to know the serial name of your device for `adb -s emulator-5554 emu kill`, then you can just use `adb -e emu kill` to kill a single emulator. This won't kill anything if you have more than one emulator running at once, but it's useful for automation where you start and stop a single emulator for a test.

Answer (score 1):

adb kill-server will kill all emulators and restart the server clean.

Comment: Does not kill or restart any emulator for me.

Comment: adb kill-server kills the server, It does not kill emulators.

Comment: it worked for me without the usb cable connected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions worked for me. I had to go the telnet way including authentication:

```
AUTH=$(cat "$HOME/.emulator_console_auth_token")

expect << EOF
spawn telnet localhost 5554
expect "OK"
send   "auth $AUTH\r"
expect "OK"
send   "kill\r"
expect "OK"
send   "exit\r"
EOF
```

The full script can be obtained with a free license from https://github.com/kullo/android-emulator-tools

---

Update: looks like this still does not reliably close the console and ADB ports (e.g. 5554,5555)

Answer (score 1):

I use this one-liner, broken into several lines for readability:

```
adb devices |
 perl -nle 'print $1 if /emulator-(\d+).device$/' |
 xargs -t -l1 -i bash -c "
   ( echo auth $(cat $HOME/.emulator_console_auth_token) ;
     echo kill ;
     yes ) |
   telnet localhost {}"
```

Answer (score 0):

List of devices attached
emulator-5584   host
emulator-5580   host
emulator-5576   host
emulator-5572   host
emulator-5568   host
emulator-5564   host
emulator-5560   host

C:\Users\Administrator>adb -s emulator-5584 emu kill
error: could not connect to TCP port 5584: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5584: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)

NOTE: gui of emulator is not running but still it's showing

SOLUTION:

```
adb kill-server
```

start emulator using:

```
emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_19
```

Answer (score 0):

To automate this, you can use any script or app that can send a string to a socket. I personally like nc (netcat) under cygwin. As I said before, I use it like this:

```
$ echo kill | nc -w 2 localhost 5554
```

(that means to send "kill" string to the port 5554 on localhost, and terminate netcat after 2 seconds.)

Answer (score 0):

This scrips can help you to kill All emulators at once:

1. Filter emulators (because you can have a mixing on physical and emus)
2. Kill all emus by ADB id

Disadvantage of this solution: if your emu just "stuck" you can't kill it with adb command and it required process kill. But that's very rare case.

```
while [ "`adb devices | grep -Eoh \"emulator-\d{0,4}\" | wc -l | tr -d ' '`" != "0" ]; do 
    echo "Connected emulators:"
    adb devices | grep -Eoh "emulator-\d{0,4}"

    for emulator in $(adb devices | grep -Eoh "emulator-\d{0,4}")
    do
        echo "Killing the emulator: $emulator"
        adb -s "$emulator" emu kill | true
    done

    sleep 10; 
done
echo "All emus has been killed"
```

Answer (score 0):

On Linux when the process became unresponsive the only way I could terminate the emulator was using the command:

```
kill -9 `pidof adb`
```

which finds the process ID of `adb` and sends a `kill -9` signal to it.

Answer (score -4):

On Windows 10, with Android Studio 2021.1.1 patch 3, the adb -s emulator-5554 emu kill command does not work, adb being not recognized.

But here's the solution using the Tool/Device Manager. Simply select the active emulator and click on x to stop it.

[image: Killing the selected emulator]

Comment: It just closes that sub-window for me on Mac.  The device is still running.