Android emulator won't run
Issues Faced:
Emulators aren't running properly.
I've installed all the necessary components for Flutter development, including Android Studio, Flutter SDK, and the Android emulator. However, the emulator doesn't start. Here's what I've done:
Checked that the Flutter and Dart plugins are installed in Android Studio.
Ensured that the AVD (Android Virtual Device) is correctly set up in Android Studio.
Tried running flutter doctor which shows no issues.
Attempted to start the emulator both from Android Studio and the command line with emulator -avd <avd_name>.
Despite these steps, the emulator fails to launch, and I don't receive any error messages; it simply does nothing. I'm using Windows 10.Error after installation Android OS
Has anyone faced a similar issue or can suggest what might be wrong?
I tried:
I installed Flutter and Android Studio, set up the necessary SDKs, and configured the Android Virtual Device (AVD). I followed the standard installation guidelines for setting up a Flutter development environment. I also verified my setup with flutter doctor, which reported no issues.
What was I expecting to happen?
I expected the Android emulator to launch successfully when initiated from Android Studio or via the command line using emulator -avd <avd_name>. This would allow me to test my Flutter applications on the Android platform.
What actually happened!
Despite all setups appearing correct and flutter doctor showing no errors, the emulator does not start when I try to launch it. There are no error messages; it simply doesn't respond or launch, leaving me unable to proceed with testing my applications.

It sounds like you've done a thorough job of setting up your Flutter environment, but there are a few additional troubleshooting steps and checks that might help you resolve the issue with your Android emulator not starting on Windows 10.
1. Check System Requirements
Ensure that your system meets the requirements for running the Android Emulator. This includes having the necessary hardware acceleration (Intel HAXM or Hyper-V) enabled.
2. Verify AVD Configuration
Double-check the configuration of your AVD:

Open Android Studio.
Go to AVD Manager.
Ensure that the AVD is using a system image that matches your system's architecture (x86 for Intel, ARM for ARM processors).
Try creating a new AVD to see if the issue persists.

3. Check Hardware Acceleration
Hardware acceleration is crucial for the emulator to run properly. Make sure it is enabled:

Intel HAXM: If you are using an Intel processor, ensure that Intel HAXM is installed and enabled.

Go to the SDK Manager in Android Studio.
Ensure that Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) is installed.
If necessary, manually install HAXM from the Intel website.
Ensure virtualization is enabled in your BIOS settings.


Hyper-V: If you are using Hyper-V instead of HAXM (common for Windows 10), ensure that it is configured correctly.

Go to Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows features on or off.
Check Hyper-V and Windows Hypervisor Platform.
Restart your computer.



4. Check for Conflicting Software
Some software can interfere with the emulator:

Disable or uninstall any software that might interfere with virtualization (e.g., other hypervisors like VirtualBox, VMware).
Ensure that your antivirus or firewall is not blocking the emulator.

5. Run Emulator from Command Line
Try running the emulator with detailed logging to identify potential issues:

Open a command prompt.
Navigate to the directory where the Android SDK is installed, typically C:\Users\<YourUsername>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator.
Run the emulator with logging enabled:
emulator -avd <avd_name> -verbose

This should provide detailed logs that can help pinpoint where the process is failing.

6. Update Graphics Drivers
Ensure that your graphics drivers are up-to-date. Outdated drivers can cause the emulator to fail.
7. Reinstall Android Studio and SDK
If the problem persists, consider reinstalling Android Studio and the Android SDK:

Uninstall Android Studio.
Delete the SDK directory to remove any potential corrupted files.
Reinstall Android Studio and set up the SDK and AVDs again.

8. Check Emulator Logs
The emulator creates logs that can help diagnose issues:

Navigate to C:\Users\<YourUsername>\.android\avd\<avd_name>.avd and look for *.log files.
Open the log files in a text editor to search for error messages or issues.

9. Ensure Sufficient System Resources
Make sure your system has enough resources (RAM, CPU) to run the emulator. Closing other resource-intensive applications might help.
Example Command Sequence
cd C:\Users\<YourUsername>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
emulator -avd <avd_name> -verbose

Summary
Following these steps should help you identify and resolve the issue preventing the Android emulator from starting. If the problem continues, the verbose logs should provide more specific information about what might be going wrong, allowing for more targeted troubleshooting.

Hi Shivangi Singh,
I appreciate your help

Reinstall Android Studio and SDK
If the problem persists, consider reinstalling Android Studio and the Android SDK:

Uninstall Android Studio.
Delete the SDK directory to remove any potential corrupted files.
Reinstall Android Studio and set up the SDK and AVDs again.
Worked!

Latest Android studio, such as Jelly Fish seems has a bug on launching Emulator.
I am sure you are using MacOs because you are building a multiplatform app, this solution will work on the MacOs.
First, open terminal and check the emulator processes.
ps -ax | grep emulator 

And then, kill the emulator currently running. If you cannot see any emulators are running but the process is live, that means it was not terminated correctly.
kill -9 PID

For example, if the PID is 12345,
kill -9 12345

See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60665011/850347

Thank you so much! I appreciate your help dear Stanley Ko. I'm using Windows 10
